# jQuery: how to apply an effect to a parent element only when the child element hasn't been clicked?

Tags: jquery

I trying to create an "edit in place" table cell. You click an edit link, and a text area appears in its place. I also only want to display the edit link when I hover over the table row. The problem I'm having with the following code is that the edit link always appears when you hover over the table row. How can I make it so that the hiding/showing, only happens when you are not currently editing.

HTML:

```
<td><a class="edit">Edit</a> $100</td>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.edit').hide();

    $('tr').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('a.edit').show();
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('a.edit').hide();
        }
    );

    $('a.edit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).after('<input type="text" style="width:100%;" />');
    });
});
```

Comment: How do you want to exit the editing mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do the `hover` in CSS. No need for javascript there. If you need to support IE6 with this feature, I'd make the javascript conditional.

Then add a class to the `<tr>` in the `click()` handler when you create the `<input>`. The CSS can keep the link hidden for the `<tr>` with the class.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/gmS46/

CSS

```
tr a.edit {
    display:none;
}
tr:hover a.edit {
    display:inline;
}
tr.hasInput a.edit {
    display:none;
}​
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.edit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).after('<input>').closest('tr').addClass('hasInput');
    });
});
```

Comment: I like your idea of doing the hover effect with CSS, since it's not necessarily related to javascript. If javascript is disabled, the hover effect will still happen.

Comment: I also realized I don't need to add a class to that table row, if I am hiding the link with javascript (since it applies the display:none style inline).

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable in the hover function, that controls when is in edit mode.

For example, you could use condition verifying that $('input',).length>0.

That is to say verifying if it exists the input filed already.

Here you have what I say:
http://jsfiddle.net/dactivo/L4zZw/

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I have used Jeditable in the past with success to accomplish the same thing: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Answer (score 0):

Things become much simpler if your cells are like this:

```
<td><a class="edit" href="#">Edit</a><span>$100</span></td>
```

The javascript needed:

```
$('tr').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('a.edit').show();
        },
        function(){
            var $a = $(this).find('a.edit');
            if (!$a.next().is('input'))
                $a.hide();
        }
    );

$('a.edit').click(function(){
    var $next = $(this).next();
    if ($next.is('input')){
        $('<span>').html($next.val()).replaceAll($next);
    } else {
        $('<input>').val($next.html()).replaceAll($next).focus();
    }
    return false;
});
```

You can check this [live jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/hxNhW/).